# Kali Linux - Newly Added Users, Config Changes Not Retaining After Reboot

Tags: linux, boot, virtualbox, iso-image, kali-linux

I have installed kali using oracle virtualbox. I set the root password with the passwd command, then added a user  the following:

## adduser --home /newusername newusername

It adds the user to the new group, creates home directory, has me set and confirm a new password, etc. When I cd .. back to the / directory, I can clearly see the new user's directory.

I then log out, and I'm able to login as the new user.

HOWEVER, after rebooting the machine, none of these changes persist. The new user is no longer there, doesn't have a folder in / directory, etc.

I also have an issue with autoamtic logins - I have been attempting to disable this feature so that no matter what, I must login in order to access the gui. I changed various values to "false" in the below config

/etc/gdm3/daemon.conf

However, as with the new user, these changes do not persist post-reboot, and I am not sure it even worked while within the same state.

My theory is it has something to do with the kali .iso file that is mounted on the VM. I've tried both checking and unchecking the "live CD/DVD" option, but it makes no difference.

If I try to unmount the .iso and boot just from the .vdi, it says it can't read the boot media. The only way I can run Kali seems to be with the installation .iso mounted, which I don't fully understand. In windows for instance you can install the OS with a CD - it is installed on the drive, thus you no longer need the CD to boot to the new OS after the initial install.

Sorry for the long winded question. Really would appreciate some help on this

Answer (score 3):

TBH if this is an issue for you, you probably shouldn't be using Kali, and you are probably are using it "wrong".

Kali is intended to be (and is) a very customized live cd/dvd that has a very specialized set of tools on it, meant to be used by people who know what they are doing.  It is not intended to be a use-as-a-desktop OS.  It is not intended to be a server of some type.  It is intended to work with and explore networks and computers on a very low level.

If you are trying to become one of those types of people, then just use the live CD as is.  They are read-only, and you don't really need persistence to learn how to use a few tools.

You MIGHT be able to boot with persistence, whihc would let you store changes from the livecd on a read/write filesystem on a drive of some type.

Comment: I am not using it as a desktop os. It is a vm, part of a virtual lab I've created

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Ivanivan is right here. The fact that kali linux is used as a tool doesn't mean we shouldn't change the password as that's just bad security measures.

To change your password, make sure you are using passwd not sudo passwd which would just change the root password. The best measure is to create a new user of your choice with a new password and change the root and default kali credential.